# After upgrade I cannot type in any windows

Tags: upgrade, input-devices

I run Ubuntu 13.10 on a 64 bits machine. Last Friday I had an automatic update.

After that I cannot type in any window, terminal, Gedit, Firefox... but I can navigate my files in File Explorer using cursor keys and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit a file name (which I own) I enter in edit mode but then I cannot key in anything.
In Software Center I can uninstall a program, when prompted for password I can key it in so the uninstallation works.
Inside XBMC the keyboard works fine.

I think it is a "permission" issue, that is my userid lost somehow its authority, but I don't know where to look.

```
uname -a
Linux Cips-Ubuntu 3.11.0-18-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 18 21:11:14 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

wmctrl -m 
Name: Compiz 
Class: N/A 
PID: N/A 
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: OFF

ps -afe |grep compiz 
emanuele 1914 1552 0 mar07 ? 00:22:49 compiz 
emanuele 21858 20207 0 11:08 pts/7 00:00:00 grep --color=auto compiz
```

Update:
I can copy/paste but I cannot type in.

OK, I have this:

```
grep ema /etc/passwd
emanuele:x:1000:1000:Emanuele,,,:/home/emanuele:/bin/bash

 ls -l  /bin/*bash*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 959168 mar 30  2013 /bin/bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 gen 11 20:08 /bin/rbash -> bash
```

Comment: Is it possible that no Window Manager is running? Have you tried hovering the mouse over the input box where you'd like to type in?

Comment: An update to 13.11? How did you find this out?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It was a "normal" update.